# Prove that vectorspace is the result of a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

So I'm given the vectorspace $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, +)$ and the subspace $U$ which contains all symmetric matrices and W which contains all skew matrices. I'm asked to prove that the given vectorspace $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} = U \bigoplus W$. How would I even start on this? I suppose I'll try to prove that every matrix is the sum of some symmetric and skew matrix?

Comment: Start by showing that $U \cap W = \{0\} $. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, using the definitions of symmetric and skew. Any matrix that is symmetric cannot be skew at the same time, except for the 0-matrix. Thus the only matrix that is within the intersection of symmetric and skew matrices is the 0-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

That is, you want to write arbitrary matrix $A$ as $A=B+C$ where $B=B^T$ and $C=-C^T$. What can you say about $A^T$= Then solve for $B$ and $C$.

Comment: A symmetric matrix has the property that $A^T = A$ and a skew matrix that $A^T = -A$. Earlier I've proven (in an earlier exercise) that A is the sum of the symmetric matrix $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$ and the skew matrix $\frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$, which would result in $A = \frac{1}{2}A + \frac{1}{2}A^T + \frac{1}{2}A - \frac{1}{2}A^T$. Is this supposed to put me on the right tracks?